# Wikimedia api and php

Tags: php, mediawiki, wiki, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

I am using the Wikimedia api and php. I need to get first main image from article and all text in article. I have got code for it, but it takes only short info and very little picture. I tried to change many parameters, but it is not working.

Code is here:

```
function get_wiki_url($title) {

    $context = stream_context_create(array(
            'http' => array(
                    'method'=>"POST",
                    'content' => $reqdata = http_build_query(array(
                            'action' => 'opensearch',
                            'search' => $title,
                            'prop' => 'info',
                            'format' => 'xml',
                            'inprop' => 'url'
                            )),
                    'header' => implode("\r\n", array(
                            "Content-Length: " . strlen($reqdata),
                            "User-Agent: MyCuteBot/0.1",
                            "Connection: Close",
                            ""
                            ))
                    )));

    if (false === $response = file_get_contents("http://ru.wikipedia.org/w/api.php", false, $context)) {
        return false;
    }

    //парсим строку
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
    return $xml->Section->Item;
}

var_dump ($pages_data = get_wiki_url("article header"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query appears to be running a search for $title (parameter `action=opensearch`); if you want the article and main image (I presume you want HTML, not wikitext), you need to use `action=parse` -- see the [Mediawiki parse documentation](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Parsing_wikitext#parse).

Example URL for getting the Hyperloop page:

```
http://ru.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=xml&page=Hyperloop
```

The documentation has details on all the options available.